# How can I SIGKILL (or SIGINT) all processes when killing a tmux session?

Tags: tmux

when I run `tmux kill-session`, it sends `SIGHUP` to all processes that are running. This often isn't enough for my purposes, and I want to send `SIGINT` or `SIGKILL`.

A command like this would do the trick:

`tmux list-panes -s -F "#{pane_pid} #{pane_current_command}" | grep -v tmux | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9`

(From this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88725/how-to-terminate-tmux-session-and-processes-it-spawned).)

How can I run this everytime I call `kill-session`? Apparently there is no `before-kill-session` hook.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

Put your command in a script like this:

```
tmux lsp ...
tmux real-kill-session "$@"
```

And make it +x. Then add `command-alias` like this:

```
set -s command-alias[100] 'real-kill-session=kill-session'
set -s command-alias[101] 'kill-session=run /path/to/kill.sh'
```

It is usually a bad idea to send everything SIGKILL though... SIGTERM or SIGINT perhaps, but they shouldn't really be any different from SIGHUP.